# Getting $last and $parent in my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I'm trying to get $last value in my directive but i don't know how to do this. I tryed so many things, i'm quite lost now.

Here is my directive call:

```
competitionvalue(ng-repeat="object in page_data.tags_data" namepopover="tagsPopover" object="object" objectkey="object.value" cssstylevalue="")
```

And this is my directive :

```
.directive('competitionvalue', function() {
    var template = '<span ns-popover="ns-popover" ns-popover-trigger="contextmenu" ns-popover-placement="bottom|left" ns-popover-template="{{ namepopover }}" ns-popover-theme="popoverMenu" ns-popover-timeout="-1"><span ng-if="object.rejectedOn"><span style="{{ stylevalue }}" class="rejected">{{ objectkey }}</span></span><span ng-if="!object.rejectedOn"><span style="{{ stylevalue }}">{{objectkey}}</span></span> LASTITEM </span>';

    function getTemplate($parent) {
        if ($parent.$parent.$last)                
            var temp = template.replace('LASTITEM', '');
        else 
            var temp = template.replace('LASTITEM', ' <span> | </span> ');
        return (temp);
    }

    var templateString = getTemplate(??);
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            namepopover: '=namepopover',
            object: '=object',
            objectkey: '=objectkey',
            stylevalue: '@cssstylevalue',
        },
        template: templateString
    }
});
```

I tryed to use:

```
link: function() {}
```

But the function is call after the return..
And I don't know how to access to my $parent.$parent in my directive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `$last` into your directive like so [Plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/4xynmg3e/)

`$parent` can be similarly passed

Comment: But now how can i do an  `ng-if=!{{index}}`

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Why would you do a `ng-if=!{{index}}`? You want to check if a valid `{{index}}` is getting passed?